# AutoIt: How can I write in an input field on a browser?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, autoit

Scenario:

I'm logged in on a website, and want to make AutoIt write in an input field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use Autoit. If you are using IE then you can use IE object for automation.

Comment: Search for something certain and unique to the input field and build off of that... i.e. a unique color somewhere near the field that you can use to orientate a click on the field. It doesn't need to be on the field, it can be something far away from it, but as long as the offset to the field remains the same, it's a viable option. Though, the above comment is a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
   #include<IE.au3>
$sUsername = "Username"
$sPassword = "Password"
$sUrl = "https://yoururl.com"
$oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 0, 1, 0, 1)
Sleep(2000)
$oHWND = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
WinSetState($oHWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
$oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 0)
$oUsername = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, 'login') ; change name !
$oPassword = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "password") ; change name !
_IEFormElementSetValue($oUsername, $sUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue($oPassword, $sPassword)
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
```

There is also an UDF FF.au3 for firefox, but I would use greasemonkey instead if you need the script only on your PC.

Comment: I am using an adaptation of your good code but i HAVE to add #requireadmin to the file otherwise it crashes when trying to do $oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 0, 1, 0, 1)  do you know why and how i could prevent this?

Comment: have a look here : https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IECreate.htm